# A simple proof that a polygon circumscribing a circle overestimates its perimeter

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, polygons

Looking at the picture below, it's easy to see why the perimeter of a polygon inscribed in a circle is an underestimation of the circle's perimeter. This follows from the triangle inequality: Any side (say $AB$) of the polygon is shorter than the circular arc with the same endpoints ($\stackrel{\frown}{AB}$). Summing all these inequalities shows the perimeter of the inscribed polygon is indeed smaller than that of the circle.

I'm wondering if there is proof that the perimeter of a circumscribed polygon always overestimates the perimeter of the circle, which is as simple as that of the inscribed polygon case. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: When all angles are acute, this follows from $\tan(\theta)>\theta$. (Consider the triangle formed by the center, a vertex and a tangency point.)

Answer (score 5):

You may use a general fact:

> If $A,B\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ are two convex bounded shapes and $A\subset B$, the perimeter of $A$ is less than the perimeter of $B$.

Proof: if $A\neq B$, you may "cut out" a slice of $B$ without touching $A$. By convexity, the perimeter of the "reduced set" $B$ is less than the perimeter of the original set $B$. If $A$ is a polygon, by iterating this argument a finite number of times you get that $A$ is a reduced version of $B$, hence $\mu(\partial A)<\mu(\partial B)$ as wanted.

Comment: But $A$ is a circle, not a polygon.

Comment: @pash: a circle is still a convex shape, so any convex polygon enclosing a circle has a perimeter that is larger than the perimeter of the circle. Equivalently, any convex polygon contained in a circle has a perimeter that is less than the perimeter of such a circle.

Comment: For $A \subset B$, the case of the *inscribed* polygon has $A$ as a polygon and $B$ as a circle; in that case, it's clear that the polygon's perimeter is less than the circle's. The question asks about the case of the *circumscribed* polygon, when $A$ is the circle and $B$ is the polygon if $A \subset B$. Your "general fact" then implies that the polygon's perimeter is larger, but the hypothesis of the last sentence of your proof is false ("If $A$ is a polygon ..."—it isn't). What am I missing? Is your proof *of* the general fact, or does it *use* the general fact to prove what was asked for?

Comment: @pash: If $A$ is not a polygon, by iterating the shown argument you get that $A$ is still a reduced version of $B$. The only difference is that you have to iterate that argument an infinite number of times, but it still works. Obviously, I'd dare to say.

Comment: *Not* obviously, I'd dare say. ... I do of course understand why what you wrote is true, now that I understand what you were trying to say. But you've hand-waved away the meat of the proof, which is the need to show that there is a process of reducing $B$ by straight cuts that has $A$ as its limit when $A$ is not a polygon. Proving that rigorously is not "simple" in the OP's meaning. (Nor does it lend any insight into the question that brought me here—which is how this fact was known to Archimedes, who invoked it in his well known iterative algorithm for bounding the value of $\pi$.)

Comment: It turns out that the answer to my question about how Archimedes knew it, by the way, is that he didn't really: he invoked it as a postulate.

Answer (score 1):

Pick a point $F$ on one of the arcs of the circle, let us say it's on arc that faces $C$ in your circumscribed quadrilateral.  Construct a line segment $GFH$ with $G$ on $BC$ and $H$ on $CD$, tangent to the circle at $F$.  $GFH$,being a straight segment, is shorter than $GC+CH$, so the circumscribed pentagon $ABGHD$ has less perimeter than the quadrilateral $ABCD$. Keep adding sides to the polygon by drawing additional tangents and the polygon perimeters will constitute a strictly monotonic decreasing sequence.  So the terms of that sequence must be greater than the limiting value which is the circumference of the circle.

Answer (score 0):

This expands
Yves Daoust's comment.

Call the point that
the tangent from $D$
touches the circle
$P$,
and the point where
$DE$ intersects the circle
$Q$.

Then
$DEQ$ is a right triangle.

Let
$t = \angle DEP$.

Then
$\tan(t)
=\dfrac{DP}{PE}
$
so
$DP
=PE \tan(t)
$.

We also have
the length of 
arc $QP= t\,PE$.

Therefore
$\dfrac{DP}{arc\ QP}
=\dfrac{PE \tan(t)}{t\,PE}
=\dfrac{\tan(t)}{t}
\gt 1
$
for
$t > 0$.

Since the same holds on both sides,
the sum of the lengths
of the two tangents
is greater than
the length of arc
$DE$
by a factor
$\dfrac{\tan(t)}{t}
$.

Answer (score 0):

This proof assumes the fact (sometimes used as a definition) that the circumference of a circle is the least upper bound of the perimeters of all polygons inscribed within it.

Def.: If $A$ is a polygon, $P(A)$ is its perimeter. If $C$ is a circle, $P(C)$ is its circumference.

Lemma: If $A$ and $B$ are convex polygons with $A \subset B$, then $P(A) \leq P(B)$. (See http://www.cut-the-knot.org/m/Geometry/PerimetersOfTwoConvexPolygons.shtml for a proof.)

Now suppose that $B$ is a polygon circumscribed about circle $C$. Let $A$ be a polygon inscribed in $C$. By the lemma, $P(A) \leq P(B)$. Taking the sup over all such polygons $A$ and using our 'fact', we have that $P(C) \leq P(B)$. Now form a second circumscribed polygon $D$ within and smaller than $B$ (one additional side is enough). Then $P(C) \leq P(D) < P(B)$, showing that $P(B)$  does indeed overestimate $P(C)$.